# Can Atmega 32 development board be used to program atmega 8 as well?

Tags: microcontroller

I wish to buy a development board thus wish to know if this is possible? I'm a beginner so which development I should use? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you talking about putting an ATMega8 on the ATMega32 board, or using the ATMega 32 to program an ATMega8?

Comment: Basically this comes down to "Help me select an AVR evaluation board". The STK 500 for example can program a wide range of AVR controllers. You may want to specify what you need / want to do.

Comment: @MattYoung I wish to know if any one board can support both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [AVRISP mkII](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AVRISPMKII.aspx) or equivalent, and ordinary breadboard, some 0.100" headers, and ordinary components (resistors, capacitors, a crystal if you want to run faster or more accurately than the built-in RC oscillator) can program any MCU in the ATmega or ATtiny series.

Comment: Thanks. Can AVR dragon be used for the same purpose?

Comment: @Sourabh I'm not familiar with the Dragon, but [Atmel lists supported devices](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AVRDRAGON.aspx?tab=devices). It sounds like the answer is probably *yes*, but don't believe everything I say.

Answer (score 3):

The pinout of an [ATmega8 (page2)](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2486-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8_L_datasheet.pdf) (regular width 28 pin DIP) is very different from an [ATmega32 (page 2)](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2503.pdf) (wide 40 pin DIP)

So apart from the fact that you have a physical challenge fitting the chip in the socket (won't fit without some sort of break out PCB), you also have a challenge matching up the various pin functions. Eg. look at AREF/VCC, RESET. So you need some serious rewiring too.

Unless you have some troubleshooting and soldering experience ***or* the board has native supports for both chips**, I'd say it is a no-go.

[image]

Comment: Isn't a board with "native supports for both chips" what he asked for in the first place?